# How to add associative arrays to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, function, associative-array

I am having trouble getting associative names of my `$_errors` array right.

```
$item1 = 'password';
$item2 = 'firstname';

$this->addError(array($item1 => 'required'))
$this->addError(array($item2 => 'required'))

private function addError($error) {
    $this->_errors[] = $error;
}

public function error($item) {
    return array_search($item, $this->_errors);
}
```

When I do a `print_r()` on `$_errors` I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [password] => required
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => required
        )
)
```

But I need it to be:

```
Array
(
    [password] => required
    [firstname] => required
)
```

So I can call 'password' like so `$this->_errors['password'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change your functions accordingly:

```
private function addError($element, $error) {
    $this->_errors[$element] = $error;
}

$this->addError($item1, 'required');
$this->addError($item2, 'required');
```

Of course this scheme will not allow you to track multiple errors for the same element at the same time; if you need to do that you have to rethink your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`list()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) construct to break the array into key-value pair and then subject it to your `$this->errors[]` array variable.

```
private function addError($error) {
    $this->_errors[] = $error;
}
```

to

```
private function addError($error) {
    list($a,$b) = each($error);    //<--------- Add the list() here
    $this->_errors[$a] = $b; //<--------- Map those variables to your array 
}
```